# map direction in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

friend 
i am making journey mapper application in this i have to show the user direction
that if user start the click the map icon then map should be show if map start where the user current stay and where he want to go then  in the map i have to show the start flag till the last journey of user and i have to show also last flag in map where the user stop in the map by setting process how i will do this in map

and i want if the user stop any where then he take some picture then that picture should be save in that part of map where the user taken a picture and user should see that picture with small icon of picture please help me in this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to use the CoreLocation and MapKit framework,
See useful links below.

http://mithin.in/2009/06/22/using-iphone-sdk-mapkit-framework-a-tutorial

http://www.icodeblog.com/2009/12/22/introduction-to-mapkit-in-iphone-os-3-0-part-2/

and step by step guide.

http://gigaom.com/apple/iphone-dev-sessions-finding-your-way-with-mapkit/

Comment: how can i dynamically get the latitude and longitude so that when the user keeps on walking from his current position his direction on the map should also keep on changing.How is this possible